# Where are ApplicationData.RoamingSettings stored when using UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, appdata

I am making a UWP app and I need to store some settings for my app in roaming AppData.
I am using this code to save it:

```cs
public bool[] options =
    {
        true
    };

public bool[] saveCBState =
    {
        true,
        true,
        true
    };

ApplicationDataContainer roamingSettings = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;

// Some not important code...

roamingSettings.Values[nameof(options)] = options;

if (options[0])
    roamingSettings.Values[nameof(saveCBState)] = saveCBState;
else
    roamingSettings.Values[nameof(saveCBState)] = null;
```

**Where can I find the settings that I just saved on my computer?**

Comment: They're right where you put them: In `ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings`. Be aware that [these settings no longer roam](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/settings-learning-track#what-do-you-need-to-know).

Comment: I want to know where are they stored ON THE COMPUTER, so I can maybe edit them externally.

Comment: The only supported way of accessing the values is to use the ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings API. The actual storage mechanism has changed over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly read the values form **RoamingSettings** whenever you want.

Like this:

```
         ApplicationDataContainer myroamingSettings = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;

        // load a setting that is local to the device
        var optionValue = myroamingSettings.Values[nameof(options)];
        var CBStateValue = myroamingSettings.Values[nameof(saveCBState)];
```

Also, please check the document that @Raymond Chen posted- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/settings-learning-track#what-do-you-need-to-know,  **ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings** gets the application settings container from the roaming app data store. **Settings stored here no longer roam (as of Windows 11)**, but the settings store is still available.